# Example for subgroups $H$ and $K$ where $HK = K H$ and neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, examples-counterexamples, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a finite group with proper non-trivial subgroups $H$ and $K$.

If $H K = K H$, then $H K$ is obviously a subgroup of $G$. It is well-known that $H$ or $K$ being normal implies that $H K$ is such a subgroup.

**Question**: Is there a finite group $G$ with proper non-trivial subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H K = K H$ and neither $H$ nor $K$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: Sure, take the subgroups generated by $(12)$ and $(34)$ inside $S_4$. It's probably more interesting to ask that neither $H$ nor $K$ be normal in $HK$.  For that case, consider subgroups where $|HK|$ is equal to $|G|$. You can always find $|HK|$ in terms of $|H|$ and $|K|$.

Comment: @Steve D: Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: For a specific example of this take $G=S_n$, $H$ the cyclic subgroup $\langle (1,2,3,\ldots,n) \rangle$, and $K \cong S_{n-1}$ a point stabilizer.

Comment: @Derek Holt: A fine example! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example In $D_4$ $H=<s>$,$K=<r^2s> $ Clearly HK is subgroup of G But None of H and K is normal subgroup.